# I can't click on an element

Tags: java, selenium

the page is fully loaded and the element is located, but for some reason it can't be clicked, I can't understand why.

My test:

```
@Test
public void test(){
    chromeDriver.get("https://alfabank.ru/currency/");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(chromeDriver, 8);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'j1I7k')]//p[contains(text(), 'USD')]")));
    WebElement clicking = chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'j1I7k')]//p[contains(text(), 'USD')]"));
    clicking.click();
}
```

Full xpatch it doesn't work either:

```
WebElement clicking = chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[6]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/button[2]"));
```

Exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (539, 1199)
```

Comment: Check if your page is autoscrolling, I had that problem before.

Comment: yes it scrolls to the desired element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the existing answer really explain what is their code is about.

Even if you launch the screen in  full screen, USD is not in Selenium view port.

Also JS is only recommended when nothing works.

I am doing with Selenium class, actions, please see below :

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://alfabank.ru/currency/");
boolean b = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs("Курсы валют — «Альфа-Банк»"));
if (b) {
    new Actions(driver).moveToElement(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div[data-test-id='caption']")))).build().perform();
    WebElement clicking = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'j1I7k')]//p[contains(text(), 'USD')]")));
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", clicking);
}
```

Comment: I have already tried using Action before, receive Exception: org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: move target out of bounds

Comment: @OttoRahn :  You've to use JavascriptExecutor, I tried many ways to do without it, none of them worked. See above, updated. here just to click we need js, I am not scrolling into the element view.

Comment: I'm in shock, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I use JS click, don't know why cannot click normally.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'j1I7k')]//p[contains(text(), 'USD')]")));
WebElement clicking = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'j1I7k')]//p[contains(text(), 'USD')]"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true); arguments[0].click()", clicking);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Apply `scrollIntoView` and then click on the `USD` using JavascriptExecutor.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);

driver.get("https://alfabank.ru/currency/");

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'j1I7k')]//p[contains(text(), 'USD')]")));
WebElement usdoption = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'j1I7k')]//p[contains(text(), 'USD')]"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", usdoption);
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", usdoption);
```

Comment: and how can you do without JS?

Comment: Yes can use JavascriptExecutor to click on the element. The above code works.